# Can't display data from my DATABASE Server

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, pdo

```
<?php
//connection to the database 
try {     
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=frostedc_movies;charset=utf8',
                    frostedc_user, 'pass'); 
 echo "connected"; 
}  
catch(PDOException $e) {  
 echo $e; //2 
} 

// select everything from the news table
$query = "SELECT * FROM movie";// Table name NOT database name 

foreach ($pdo->query($query) as $row) {
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td width='150'>".$row['movietitle']."</td>";
        echo "<td width='150'>".$row['genre']."</td>";
        echo "<td width='150'>".$row['LastViewed']."</td>";
        echo "<td width='150'>".$row['Location']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "<br>";
echo "
    <form>
        <p>Please Enter a Movie Title</p>
        <input type='text' name='new_movie' />
        <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
    </form>";
echo "
    <form>
        <p>Please Enter the Genre</p>
        <input type='text' name='movie_genre' />
        <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
    </form>";
echo "
    <form>
        <p>Please Enter the Last View Date</p>
        <input type='text' name='last_view' />
        <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
    </form>";
echo "
    <form>
        <p>Please Enter the Location</p>
        <input type='text' name='movie_loca' />
        <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
    </form>";




$pdo = null;
```

?>

this is the new updated code.  I am trying to use the inputs to enter data into my database.
I have researched how to do this, but so far I haven't got anything to work.  Any thoughts?  Also would it be easier for me to use include and make the inputs in html? if so could i use them to enter the data into the db?

Comment: mysql() is deprecated...use mysqli()

Comment: your mixing PDO with mysql

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have tagged your question **PDO** I have removed all unneeded code from your example.

```
<?php
//connection to the database 
try {     
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=frostedc_movies;charset=utf8',
                    user, 'password'); //1
    echo "connected"; 
}  
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e; //2 
} 
// select everything from the news table
$query = "SELECT * FROM myTable";// Table name NOT database name 
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
foreach ($pdo->query($query) as $row) {//3
    echo "<td>".$row['movietitle']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['genre']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['LastViewed']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Location']."</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
// disconnect from the database
$pdo = null;//5
?>
```

The number comments

1 Setting character set [**Manual**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php)

2 Echoing error message only for development.In production you should either do something  with it or remove try/catch.

3 As there are no parameters use [**query()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)

4 For **utf8** Prior to  [**PHP 5.3.6**](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php)

5 Changed `mysql_close();`(mysql_) to `$pdo = null;` (PDO)

Comment: Thank you!  I am trying to learn PHP and PDO and MYSQL to access my database, but as you can tell I'm not doing so hot...

Comment: I get an error
Warning: mysql_close(): no MySQL-Link resource supplied in /home/frostedc/public_html/test/index.php on line 24

Comment: @NathanielMiller Sorry my wrong. Didn't provide proper code for closing database connection. See edit

Comment: thats ok, thank you so much for you help!

any advice where I can learn how to do the above code better?  I'm trying to be able to add and change the information from the table using user input.  So far I'm confused from all of the sights I have looked at

Comment: @NathanielMiller Here is a good [**tutorial**](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you find my answer useful you can accept it. You can always ask a new question just make sure you provide code,any errors,etc.

Comment: to update the database information, i have an html input.  how do I use that to enter it into the database?

code:

Comment: echo " <form>
   <p>Please Enter a Movie Title</p>
   <input type='text' name='new_movie' />
   <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
  </form>";
 echo "
  <form>
   <p>Please Enter the Genre</p>
   <input type='text' name='movie_genre' />
   <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
  </form>";
 echo "
  <form>
   <p>Please Enter the Last View Date</p>
   <input type='text' name='last_view' />
   <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
  </form>";
 echo "
  <form>
   <p>Please Enter the Location</p>
   <input type='text' name='movie_loca' />
   <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
  </form>";

Comment: Should be new question.<?php 
$new_movie = isset($_POST['new_movie']) ? $_POST['new_movie'] : ''; 
require("dbinfo.php");//database info
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password);  
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `movies` (`id`, `name`) values (NULL, ? )"); 
$stmt->bindParam(1, $new_movie);  
$stmt->execute(); 
$dbh = null;
?> 
<form action="postInsert.php" method="post"> 
<p>Please Enter a Movie Title</p>
<input type='text' name='new_movie' />
<input type='submit' value='Submit' />  
</form>

Answer (score 1):

You are doing 2 wrong things here

**First :** Mixing **`PDO`** with **`MySQL`** 
**Second :** `$query = "SELECT * FROM myDB";` **You cant select from a Database.. You need to do a SELECT from your TABLE !** (Are you sure `myDB` is your table ?)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php // connect to the database
  $host = 'localhost';
  $username = 'user';
  $pass = 'password';
  $conn=mysql_connect($host,$username,$pass)or die(mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db("myDB");
  // select everything from the news table
  $query = "SELECT * FROM news";
  $result = mysql_query($query);

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    echo "<table>
            <tr>
              <td>".$row['movietitle']."</td>
              <td>".$row['genre']."</td>
              <td>".$row['LastViewed']."</td>
              <td>".$row['Location']."</td>
            </tr>
          </table>";
  }

  // disconnect from the database
  mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: You have extra ( on while :-)

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
<?php // connect to the database
$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'user';
$pass = 'password';
mysql_connect($host,$username,$pass);
mysql_select_db("myDB");
// select everything from the news table
$query = "SELECT * FROM `tablename`";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
while( ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)))
{
echo "<td>".$row['movietitle']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['genre']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['LastViewed']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['Location']."</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
// disconnect from the database
mysql_close();
?>
```